# PHP 2 arrays - merge values existing in both arrays to one array

Tags: php, arrays

I have 2 arrays:

```
$array1 = array(1,2,3,4,5);
$array2 = array(3,4,5,6,7);
```

Is there any PHP function that does this?

```
$finalArray = unknown_php_function($array1,$array2);
// result: $finalArray = array(3,4,5);
```

It merges both arrays and removes values which aren't present in both arrays. Do I have to build a foreach cycle or is there an easier way? Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You want [`array_intersect`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect.php) for this, basically the intersection of two sets (arrays, in this case), just like in school. :-)

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I want. It's probably easily googlable but I didn't know the English expression intersection, teachers in my school teach in different language brb...

Comment: Yeah, that happens even if you're a native speaker of English :) This is a handy list of array functions in PHP: http://nl3.php.net/manual/en/ref.array.php

Answer (score 3):

You're looking for [`array_intersect()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect.php). Here is a demo:

```
$array1 = array(1,2,3,4,5);
$array2 = array(3,4,5,6,7);

$finalArray = array_intersect($array1,$array2);
print_r($finalArray);
```

Outputs:

```
Array
(
    [2] => 3
    [3] => 4
    [4] => 5
)
```